# generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I have some troubles with identification of the generating set in the next group:

If I want to create a group $\mathbb{Z}$ from commutative monoid $\mathbb{N}$ I should take $\mathbb{N}^2$ and factorize it by $(n_1,m_1) = (n_2,m_2)$ if $n_1+m_2 = n_2+m_1$. After that, the operation $-$ is obvious. 
I try to figure out what is the generating element in this new group. I know, that a $\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to a free one-element group $<a>$. What is playing the role of this $a$ in the group from factorset? That is not $(1,1)$ because of $(k,k) = (0,0)$ --- identity element.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: ${}{}{}{}(1,0)$?

Comment: What you call “factorize it” is usually called “mod out by” (taking a quotient, not writing it as a product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pair $(a,b)$ represents the integer $a-b$. So the integer $1$ is represented by the pair $(n+1,n)$ for any natural number $n$.

Comment: Oh ye, it was obvious, thx..

Comment: And I can express any element of group from $(n+1,n)$? Only $(k,0)$, no?

Comment: @Justdoit 1 generates the integers as a group, which means you're allowed to take inverses... to generate the integers as a monoid, you also need $-1$.

Comment: So, we have two generating elements: $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in the group structure on the factor of $\mathbb{N}^2$? Not one, like in $\mathbb{Z}$? Or I do not really understand..

Comment: @Justdoit No: As a group, $\mathbb{N}^2/\sim$ is generated by a single element, $(1,0)$, just like how the (isomorphic) group $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$. This is because the subgroup of $\mathbb{N}^2/\sim$ generated by $(1,0)$ contains the inverse of $(1,0)$, which is $(0,1)$, and hence it contains $(n,0) = (1,0) + \dots + (1,0)$ and $(0,n) = (0,1)+\dots+(0,1)$, and every element of $\mathbb{N}^2$ is equivalent to $(n,0)$ or $(0,n)$ for some natural number $n$.

Comment: Maybe I confused things by mentioning monoids in my earlier comment. My point was just that there's a difference between the sub*group* generated by a set and the sub*monoid* generated by a set. The subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, but the submonoid of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $1$ is $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think that I stacked at this moment: "This is because the subgroup of  $\mathbb{N}^2$ generated by $(1,0)$ contains the inverse of $(1,0)$, which is $ (0,1) $". Why it should contain it? How can I compute $(0,1)$ from $(1,0)$? By summate $(1,0)$ with $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Justdoit Do you know the definition of "subgroup"? Do you understand why the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $1$ contains $-1$?

Comment: It is a group with a similar operation but on the subset of original group

Comment: Because if it is not, it won't be a group, yes?

Comment: Right - every element of a group must have an inverse.

Comment: But in our situation, we create a group structure on the fuctorset. We shouldn't have inverse elements before we prove that this is a group.. I understand, that for $(n,m)$ the $(m,n)$ will be inverse element. And we can generate them from $(1,0)*n + (0,1)*m$ and $(1,0)*m+(0,1)*n$, where $*$ --- n-times summation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108895/discussion-between-alex-kruckman-and-just-do-it).